# Correct and economical way to test if object has values in php?

Tags: php, object, if-statement, null

if i want to check a user exist after running the following code

```
$user = User::find->(1);
```

whats the correct and economical way to check if object has values in php?

```
if(!empty($user))
```

or

```
if($user)
```

or

```
if(isset($user))
```

Comment: This depends on the possible return values of `User::find()`. We can't guess them. If you are unsure about the usage of the functions in question, read their documentations.

Answer (score 1):

```
is_null($user)
```

will tell you if the variable is null or not. Is this what you're looking for? Otherwise,

```
isset($user)
```

will tell you if $user is set and not null

Answer (score 0):

As someone said It depends on what is being returned.. If what is being returned is an instance of User You could also check of the variable is an instance of:

```
$user = User::find->(1);

if ($user instanceof User) {
    echo '$user contains all the data in a User instance';
}
```

You could do:

```
is_null($user)
```

But that doesn't guarantee that it is an User instance.. but if its returning something else thats not an instance of User then you coul probably use it..